# Minimized Hololens application stops recognize air-taps - events doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

Minimized Hololens application stops recognize air-taps.
It happens when you've let the app go idle for a while and then try to restart your session.
the gaze will turn into a doughnut but it won't do anything when you air tap.

```
void OnApplicationPause(bool paused)
{
    if (!paused)
    {
        GestureListener.Instance.OnDisable();
        GestureListener.Instance.OnEnable();
    }
}
```

I do this each time I invoke app but it doesn't help.